# Custom ad sizes for iAd and AdMob

Tags: ios, admob, iad

I have both iAd and AdMob in my application. Can I customize the ad sizes in my application to 320x250? Or are only predefined sizes mentioned in the documentation possible, for example 320x50?

I think it is not possible, but I just want to confirm this.

Comment: *I know this is not possible.* Sounds like you answered your own question...

Answer (score 0):

Yes , Its possible to make custom size with AdMob using DFPBannerView. Please try with below code -

```
// Define custom GADAdSize 320 x 220
GADAdSize customAdSize = GADAdSizeFromCGSize(320, 220);

self.adBanner = [[DFPBannerView alloc] initWithAdSize:customAdSize];
```

Please check below url for more details -

https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/dfp/ios/banner

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I had already checked out this. Practically I'm unable to see it.

Comment: Please try - request.testDevices = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                       GAD_SIMULATOR_ID,
                       nil]; and check response coming from server if its is not nil